# horizontal line in table does not cover full width

Tags: tables, hline

Below I have the code to create a table in latex, but the horizontal dashed line is not drawn over the full width of the table.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Aggregated sales data of all products} % title of Table
\label{dfbig}
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c |} % centered columns (7 columns)
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
Product & Week & Sales Quantity & Subgroup & Group & Category\\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
%heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
$p_1$ & $w_1$ & $Q_1(p_1,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_1)$ & $R(p_1)}$ & $C(p_1)$ \\ 
$p_1$ & $w_2$ & $Q_2(p_1,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_1)$ & $R(p_1)$ & $C(p_1)$ \\ 
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
$p_1$ & $w_{n_w}$ & $Q_{w_n}(p_1,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_1)$ & $R(p_1)$ & $C(p_1)$ \\ 
\hdashline
$p_2$ & $w_1$ & $Q_1(p_2,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_2)$ & $R(p_2)$ & $C(p_2)$ \\ 
$p_2$ & $w_2$ & $Q_2(p_2,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_2)$ & $R(p_2)$ & $C(p_2)$ \\ 
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
$p_2$ & $w_{n_w}$ & $Q_{w_n}(p_2,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_2)$ & $R(p_2)$ & $C(p_2)$ \\
\hdashline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
\hdashline
$p_{n_p}$ & $w_1$ & $Q_1(p_n,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_{n_p})$ & $R(p_{n_p})$ & $C(p_{n_p})$ \\ 
$p_{n_p}$ & $w_2$ & $Q_2(p_n,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_{n_p})$ & $R(p_{n_p})$ & $C(p_{n_p})$ \\ 
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
$p_{n_p}$ & $w_{n_w}$ & $Q_{w_n}(p_n,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_{n_p})$ & $R(p_{n_p})$ & $C(p_{n_p})$ \\ [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I get this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Show us the definition of the command `\hdashline`. I guess it contains some `\cline{}`!

Comment: @Sigur Maybe the `\hdashline` is from the `arydshln` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first row, you had an extra brace in `$R(p_1)}$`, remove this and recompile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Aggregated sales data of all products} % title of Table
\label{dfbig}
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{| *7{c|} } % centered columns (7 columns)
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
Product & Week & Sales Quantity & Subgroup & Group & Category\\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
%heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
$p_1$ & $w_1$ & $Q_1(p_1,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_1)$ & $R(p_1)$ & $C(p_1)$ \\ 
$p_1$ & $w_2$ & $Q_2(p_1,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_1)$ & $R(p_1)$ & $C(p_1)$ \\ 
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
$p_1$ & $w_{n_w}$ & $Q_{w_n}(p_1,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_1)$ & $R(p_1)$ & $C(p_1)$ \\ 
\hdashline
$p_2$ & $w_1$ & $Q_1(p_2,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_2)$ & $R(p_2)$ & $C(p_2)$ \\ 
$p_2$ & $w_2$ & $Q_2(p_2,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_2)$ & $R(p_2)$ & $C(p_2)$ \\ 
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
$p_2$ & $w_{n_w}$ & $Q_{w_n}(p_2,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_2)$ & $R(p_2)$ & $C(p_2)$ \\
\hdashline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
\hdashline
$p_{n_p}$ & $w_1$ & $Q_1(p_n,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_{n_p})$ & $R(p_{n_p})$ & $C(p_{n_p})$ \\ 
$p_{n_p}$ & $w_2$ & $Q_2(p_n,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_{n_p})$ & $R(p_{n_p})$ & $C(p_{n_p})$ \\ 
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ \\
$p_{n_p}$ & $w_{n_w}$ & $Q_{w_n}(p_n,\ell_{j})$ & $S(p_{n_p})$ & $R(p_{n_p})$ & $C(p_{n_p})$ \\ [1ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]